# LocalDB database on fly for entity framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, localdb

is possible to create an mdf file on fly (at runtime) and use it with entity framework 6 in a code first approach?

I need something like this:

```
if (mydb.mdf not exists)
    createmdf();

mycontext ctx = new mycontext(mydb.mdf connection string)
ctx.CreateDatabase();
```

Thank you

Comment: was my answer good for you ?. Please consider to accepts the answers that helped you in your question. Because as i noticed that you didn't accept any answer for all your question.

Comment: Hi Wahid, thank you for your attention. No, unfortunately your answer is not what I was looking for. A lot of people often copy and past some text hoping to gain some points. It's not your case but, you know... The hard thing to do is that I don't want to use the config connection string, but I want to specify one each time. I want to use a MDF file as a project-file for my application so I can't use the same file specified in the config section. My aplication must be capable to create and manage different mdf file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
```

You could do something like this in your context constructor

```
public YourDBContext(): base("YourDBConnectionString") 
{
    Database.SetInitializer<YourDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<YourDBContext>());
    //Database.SetInitializer<YourDBContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourDBContext>());
}
```

This will use your connection string in the `web.config` file and try to find the database. If the database doesn't exist then it will create it according to the model that you defined.

***Update :***

Please look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6591278/105445) too

Comment: Hi @WahidBitar - for the benefit of onlooking noobs, can you please always explain why/how your solution actually solves the problem? :)

Comment: @TarynEast - I added some explanation hope this was helping. And thanks for your support :)